# Is Unit Testing Costlier in iOS Development?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

Do you think unit testing is an overfkill for iOS Development?

I read this [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/high-quality-in-software-development.html). The author says that for an iOS App , unit testing takes too much of our effort. Share your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing is never overkill. You have to define what you want to test first. And then how you are going to test it. If it takes to much effort you have a 'test smell'. Normally you should workout how you write the code in such a manner that it is testable.

Comment: But how do you test the Application logic?

Comment: By using a mocking framework if available or design the code so that they can be tested without mocking using dependency injection.